# How to replace backslashes to single backslash from the string?

Tags: php

for example I have a string

```
$str = "///a//b/c////d.html";
```

How to make it more compatible with valid url?

Comment: what do you mean by `more comfortable`?

Comment: Why does it have so many ***(forward)*** slashes in it to begin with? And what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I mean it must be like ``$outstr = "/a/b/c/d.html";``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/[\/]+/', '/', $str);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/koWN5)

Answer (score 0):

To replace multiple slashes with one, You can to use regular expressions like so:

```
$str = "///a//b/c////d.html";

function slug($str) {
    $str = strtolower(trim($str));
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-.]/', '-', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/-+/', "/", $str);
    return $str;
}

echo slug($str);
```

Comment: not working. it is returning '/a/b/c/d/html' instead of '/a/b/c/d.html'

Comment: it will replace all the words in url, I need only a single slashes if they plural.